# Deserialization with JSON objects which fields can be of different types

Tags: java, json

I have the following json file:

```
{
"authors": 

[{"id":"author7",
"book":[
[
{
"value":{"pages":123}}]]},
{
    "id": "author3",
    "book": [
    [
    {
    "value": {
    "title": "LOTR"
    }
    },
    {
    "value": {
    "boolean": false
    }
    },
    ],
    [
    {
    "value": {
    "pages": 350
    }
    },
    {
    "value": {
    "boolean": false
    }
    },
    ],
    [
    {
    "value": {
    "boolean": false
    }
    },
    {
    "value": {
    "pages": 150
    }
    },
    ]
    ]
    },
}
```

I want to be able to create an object of Author but I am having problems while mapping the Json file with the Java classes I have created.

I understand that, while mapping the json file with the java classes, Authors class should have as fields

```
public class Authors{
    private String authorId;
    private Book book;
}
```

Class Book should be like this

```
public class Book {
        
    private List<Values> values
    
    public Book() {
    }
}
```

But what about class Values?

```
public class Values{
        
    private int pages;
    private Boolean bool;
    private String title;

    
    public Values() {
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to map it? Because I see that if I create an object of Values it will ask me to modify the constructor or create a new constructor for each different object that comes from Json

Thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please don't post half/incomplete JSON structure in the question body. In this case, you're missing the closing of JSON structure and starting portion of the JSON is also a bit confusing. If it's too long to post the JSON here, trim out repeated data and [edit] the question, update the details.

Comment: Thank you. I think now is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way out would to be to define Values by type 'object' as,

```
public class Book {           
    private List<Object> values
}
```

This way you won't run into the issue of having properties with null values when they don't exist in the JSON. Also, the JSON would be entirely parsed into an object even if new properties are get introduced (or which may not be defined under values class, as you have done above causing those not being mapped to the object).

However, when you are using 'object', be mindful with your logic that uses this parsed object. Although, you are assured to access the properties from the object as in the JSON, you will have to conditionally check whether the nessacary property exists first in each logical context to avoid possible undefined value errors.

Comment: I wrote it like you said but it tells me that cannot resolve the symbol 'any'

Comment: use 'Object' type. 'any' is used in javascript.

Comment: Thank you, now I get it. And the class Value should be filled with the three type of parameters that "values" in JSON accepts? Like this: 

```
public class Values{
        
    private int pages;
    private Boolean bool;
    private String title;

    
    public Values() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, what I explained is, you have 2 options to go about this. One, as I mentioned, you can, used Object - a generic type for capturing all the different forms of Value object (that as a generic. So, the Object type, don't have a schema/structure). This way, you will have generic objects that will conform exactly with the JSON scheme for values individually for each instance of 'value'.

Comment: Other is, you can go ahead defining 'Value' class, but each of its properties defined with default values i.e. null so, that even if the schema for Value is variant, only the property contain the value in JSON would be mapped to the object with that value only for the matching property. Rest of the properties that don't exist in the JSON for that particular 'Value' instance, would be null.

Comment: Explain it in reverse, by 1st method, if you deserialise again, you should get the exact same JSON you serialised. By 2nd method, you will get a JSON which is slightly different to the original JSON, in a way that all value instances in the JSON would contain all the properties that exist, but with values only for those that contained values in the original json, rest with null or the default value you define the class with.

Comment: @maikelsabatico does this explanation works for you?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I will check later if I manage to make it run.